# Non-commuting Hermitian operators A, B cannot have $[A,B]=i~q~I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let A,B be *finite-dimensional* Hermitian operators and show that $[A,B]= q~ i~I$ cannot hold for $q$ a real constant and $I$ the identity matrix. *

---

One of several ideas that has not worked: I guess by definition

$AB-BA = q~i~I = q~i\sum_j |j\rangle\langle j| $

Neither AB nor BA is Hermitian, since AB Hermitian iff $[A,B]=0.$

So let $|\psi\rangle,\lambda_1$ be an eigenvector, eigenvalue associated with AB and $\lambda_2, \langle \phi|$ with $BA$. Then

$\langle \phi|AB|\psi\rangle-\langle \phi|BA|\psi\rangle = \lambda_1\langle \phi|\psi\rangle -\lambda_2 \langle \phi|\psi\rangle =q~i \sum \langle\phi|j \rangle\langle j|\psi\rangle$

This only seems to allow us to say that $\lambda_1-\lambda_2$ is imaginary. I seem to be pretty far off course, any suggestions appreciated.

*The problem is from Commins, Quantum Mechanics (Cambridge, 2014)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** What is the trace of a commutator?

Comment: @daniel Definitely take another look. Hermiticity of $A$ and $B$ have nothing to do with this problem by the way. It holds for all $A$ and $B$. Try computing the trace of both sides explicitly.

Comment: Yes, trace (LHS)  = 0 =/= trace (RHS). Thanks.

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is circumvented in infinite dimensions since the trace operation is no longer defined for the identity operator (i.e., the identity is not trace-class). The significance of all this is to show that the canonical commutation relations $[x,p]=i\hbar$ cannot have a finite dimensional representation. Indeed, the unique (up to unitary equivalence) representation of the canonical commutation relations is the standard Schrodinger representation on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ as guaranteed by the [Stone-von Neumann theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem).